# I can't Resize an ntfs drive from Ubuntu (chkdsk has been run, and no errors were found, disk was defragmented)

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, mount, hard-drive, ntfs

I want to resize my 2 TB windows partition on a second hard drive on my desktop however there is a warning flag on gparted that gives the following two messages:

```
 The device /dev/sdc3 doesn't exist

Unable to read the contents of this file system!
Because of this, some operations may be unavailable.
The cause might be a missing software package.
The following list of software packages is required for ntfs file system support:  ntfs-3g / ntfsprogs.
```

I tried running chkdsk and the program returned with no errors.
Running ntfsfix on the drive returns the following:

```
Failed to determine whether /dev/sdc3 is mounted: No such file or directory
Mounting volume... Failed to access '/dev/sdc3': No such file or directory
Error opening '/dev/sdc3': No such file or directory
FAILED
Attempting to correct errors... Failed to access '/dev/sdc3': No such file or directory
Error opening '/dev/sdc3': No such file or directory
FAILED
Failed to startup volume: No such file or directory
Failed to access '/dev/sdc3': No such file or directory
Error opening '/dev/sdc3': No such file or directory
Volume is corrupt. You should run chkdsk.
```

Any help is greatly appreciated Thank you!

Edit1: Also gparted seems unable to make any changes to the partitions on the drive. I resized the partition on windows and the change doesn't show up in gparted.

Edit 2:  The drive was an internal 2 TB HDD, I'm running Xubuntu 18.04. For some reason the ubuntu seemed to have written it's own GPT partition table over top of the windows MBR one so ubuntu was reading the GPT and ignoring the MBR that it identified as faulty. I used a tool( I'll try to find it) to remove the GPT partition table however that broke the windows one. I Just decided re reformat the disk to from ubuntu since it seemed too messy.

Comment: Do you have a MBR or GPT partition table? How big is the drive? Internal or external USB?

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]